# BIRT 4.5.0 new theme/design

Tags: user-interface, icons, birt

I recently downloaded the last version of BIRT 4.5.0 (All in one version) : http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/

The GUI now looks similar to this :

[image]

I just want to triple-check I didn't miss anything with this new version ... can anyone confirm he's also seeing black & white icons ?

Note that it's not disturbing me at all ;) ... but just want to ensure it wouldn't be a sign of anything bad installed/configured ...

Comment: I can confirm this new theme is normal, nothing wrong here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The black and white icons are the new icons for the open source and commercial BIRT Designer.